# where() providing unusual output

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I am examining the [Accidental Drug Related Deaths](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/accidental-drug-related-deaths-january-2012-sept-2015) dataset. There are, as per `deaths.info()`, 5105 rows, with 5095 non-null values in `deaths['MannerofDeath']`. There are six unique values contained in `deaths['MannerofDeath']`; those are `array(['Accident', 'accident', nan, 'Pending', 'ACCIDENT', 'Natural'], dtype=object)`. I'm trying to assess how many are accidental using the following line:

```
len(deaths.where(deaths['MannerofDeath'].isin(['Accident','accident','ACCIDENT'])))
```

The output for this is 5105, which is, naturally, incorrect. I'm not sure how to correct it, though--in fact, `len(deaths.where(deaths['MannerofDeath'] == 'Natural'))` produces an output of 5105 as well.

Where am I going wrong in creating this `where()` function?

Comment: Why is this unusual? Have you [read the documentation for what `pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)? Because clearly, what you *expect* it to do isn't what it is doing...

Comment: Fair enough, I may have misunderstood the documentation when I read it; I skimmed it, assuming it to be the same as `np.where()`. ...That being said, how would you recommend I do what I am actually trying to do?

Comment: It *does* do something similar to `np.where`... why do you think that the size of the array would be different? What you probably meant was boolean indexing, `len(deaths[deaths['MannerofDeath'].isin(['Accident','accident','ACCIDENT'])])`, but probably more efficiently, you just want `deaths['MannerofDeath'].isin(['Accident','accident','ACCIDENT']).sum()`